# Angular 13 load/compile dynamic Angular component from HTML string

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, angular-directive

I want to **load or compile** `Angular elements as HTML` from `string` into my component.

I am getting HTML string from API as a string and I want to load and render all HTML structural directives from that string.

```
 let str = `<div>Testing here
  <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]">{{i}}</div>
 </div>`;

setTimeout(() => {
  const componentRef: ComponentRef<DynamicComponent> =
    this.createDynamicComponent<DynamicComponent>(
      DynamicComponent,
      this.vc
    );
  componentRef.instance.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str);
});
```

But it output as instead of `ngFor` loop it simply loads as string.

```
Load Dynamic HTML
Testing here
{{i}}
```

[Here is sample I tried](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-template-jstfwx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Here above is just sample HTML string. It can be anything from server like `ngIf` or any other inbuilt `Angular` directives

I have also tried using custom element `createCustomElement` but in that also I was not able to render `Angular directives runtime from string`.

**Edit 1**

Similar thing is working fine for [This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgxvwl?file=src/app/dynamic-template.component.ts) example but If I download and run locally same error.

Comment: Yeah.. this won’t work I’m afraid.

Comment: @MikeOne In older AngularJS, we were able to use parse syntax and compile that at run time. I am not sure how to do in Angular 13.

Comment: I haven't used Angular since they called A1 to A2 an "Upgrade"; but wouldn't this allow (potential) XSS attacks? Its the same behavior as an ``eval``

Comment: Yes I agree it will allow XSS attacks, But as I have some features where I am allowing user to create HTML template as save it into DB and want to load at run time.

Comment: Angular determines what directives to apply at compile time. It does no longer parse those directives runtime. There are some really nasty tricks that would get you close to what you need, bit the downsides to that are usually too great. This might become a little easier in an upcoming release of Angular though (dynamic hostDirectives).. I’d rethink this if I were you.

Comment: @MikeOne it will be great if you share some article to achieve it. mostly want to use basic syntax like ngFor, ngIf and click event from HTML

Comment: this article may help!
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/compiling-angular-templates-runtime-dima-slivin/

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the example at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgxvwl?file=src/app/dynamic-template.component.ts) and got it working. You can see the complete code here - https://github.com/phalgunv/Angular-Dynamic-Component-From-String

It required a couple of fixes needed to get it working for prod build.

Comment: Neat implementation